# set azure storage account as current storage account powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

I am having the azure storage account(classic) and I can't set it as current storage account in powershell as it shows `Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount : The Resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/devstorageaccount' under resource group
'DEVENV' was not found.`

I used `Add-AzureRMAccount`. 
When I login using `Add-AzureAccount` it returns nothing except error as I'm just having `owner` role for the subscription.
so how can I set the storage account as current storage account in powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount` expects the storage account to be a `Resource Manager (ARM) Storage Account` and you mentioned that your storage account is a `Classic` storage account.

Please try by using an ARM Storage Account.

Comment: Can't I use that same classic storage account by using any other powershell command to set that as current storage account?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

> how can I set the storage account as current storage account in powershell?

We can use [set-azuresubcription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn408531.aspx) to do that.

```
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "xxx" -CurrentStorageAccountName "xxx"
```

Please have a try to use the following code:

```
Add-AzureAccount 

Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "subcription name" -CurrentStorageAccountName "storage name"

Get-AzureSubscription
```

[image]

Comment: I tried and it shows `Set-AzureSubscription : The subscription name 'XXX' doesn't exist.` ??? (I have used `add-azurermaccount` because I can't login using add-azureaccount` as I 'm not admin or co-admin. I'm just having owner role)

Comment: same error - `Select-AzureSubscription : The subscription name "xxx" doesn't exist.`

Comment: If you use arm account, as Gaurav mentioned classic storage account can not be set as current storage

Comment: I 'm having doubt that what do you guys mean by arm account ? Is it about the subscription or azure account ?

Comment: See my answer about ARM thing here (though it is about VMs but you can understand the difference between ARM & Classic there): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34737272/what-is-the-difference-between-virtual-machine-classic-and-virtual-machine-in-az/34737643#34737643.

Comment: This is really the answer to OPs question....I don't know why THIS was the way to set your storage account to current in classic though, makes no sense