# How to create A0-A4 types of VM in new Azure portal?

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

As per the VM instance plans shown on [this page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/virtual-machines/linux/),
I wish to create A1 type of VM instance. However on Azure portal, this instance plan simply does not show up when I try to create VM.

After some some digging around, I found that these plans **A0-A4** are only available in **VM classic**.

I know the difference between [VM classic and new VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34737272/what-is-the-difference-between-virtual-machine-classic-and-virtual-machine-in-az). But I also came to know after a bit reading that Microsoft doesn't recommend **VM classic** anymore.

So should I still go with VM classic as it provides more economical plans? Will I face any issues in long run? Or is it simply that Microsoft has not ported these plans to newer VM types?

Comment: Not sure why down vote. Seems legit question. Never asked before.

Comment: Somebody downvoted?  Boooooo.  I had the exact same question and found this.  UpV!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wish to create A1 type of VM instance. However on Azure portal, this
>   instance plan simply does not show up when I try to create VM.

You can still create A1 type of VM instance using Resource Manager deployment. The trick is to use `HDD` for `VM disk type` instead of `SSD`.

[image]

Once you do that, you should see A0 - A4 sizes in VM size blade.

[image]

Comment: I'm new to Azure.  Does the O/S factor in?  I'm trying to make an A0 with Windows Server 2012.  I got the HDD option selected, but the "View All" does not show up and all I have is a DS1_V2 plan ($55/month).  :(

Comment: Looks like O/S matters.  June/2017 I was to able to pick "Ubuntu Server 16.10" and I saw A0.  I tried a few different Windows Server 2012 ones, and best I got was 37.20 F1  Standard or F1s  Standard   WHY DON'T THEY LIST THEM IN ORDER OF PRICE???? (or allow some basic sorting).  Dang you M.S.

Comment: So if I pick "Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 on Windows Server 2016" I get A0 option.  Go figure.  Maybe they don't want old O/S running.