# How to associate Network Security Group to a Ubuntu Classic VM in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I created a VM without assigning a Network Security Group. Now, I am trying to assign the one group thats already created to the VM but the group is not listed for assignment.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need click `Network security group`, then you could see your Network Security Group.

[image]

Note: Your VM is a classic VM, you only could see classic network security group.

[image]

Comment: It means if you create a network security groups(arm mode), when you click `Network security group`, you could not see it. You need `create Network security groups(classic)`.

Comment: None of my Network Security Groups are listed in When I click on the arrow (Network Security Group) in the pic I posted.

Comment: Yes, it means no network security group(classic). You need create one firstly. In other words, you create a arm mode nsg. See my second screenshot.

Comment: @Minisha Also check this screenshot https://imgur.com/a/aMKgy An classic mode VM does not support associate arm mode nsg.

Comment: Whats the difference between a normal VM and a classic VM?

Comment: You could check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34737272/what-is-the-difference-between-virtual-machine-classic-and-virtual-machine-in-az). Classic mode is a older mode.